# jQuery clone element and avoid taking parent node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to clone HTML element like this:

```
  var $div = $('#world-map-gdp').clone();
  $("#world-map-gdp2").html($div);
  $("#world-map-gdp2").removeAttr('style').css("height", "400px").css("display","block");
```

The original HTML element looks like this:

```
 <div id="world-map-gdp" style="height:400px !important; position: absolute !important; left: -999em !important;">

 </div>
```

I want to clone only body of this element, not the div itself, so just body which is in between:

```
<div> </div>
```

Tag... How can I do this?

Comment: what's inside of it, just clone that

Comment: @Pabs123 the content is dynamically populated by jQuery later on,  I can see it has SVG tag inside of it, how can I say to clone from svg tag inside div?

Comment: have you tried something like document.querySelector('#world-map-gdp').innerHTML? Set that to a variable, then use innerHTML on the second element to set the cloned content.

Comment: var $div = $('#world-map-gdp').children().clone(true, true); works quite nicely, just tested it =)

Answer (score 1):

```
var body = document.querySelector('#world-map-gdp').innerHTML;
```

This will get just the innerHTML content for the selected element, then use the body variable to populate the innerHTML on the second element:

```
document.querySelector('#world-map-gdp2').innerHTML = body;
```

Or, if you wanted to use jQuery:

```
var $body = $('#world-map-gdp').html(); 
$('#world-map-gdp2').html($body);
```

Comment: How about var $div = $('#world-map-gdp').children().clone(true, true);?

Comment: If it works sure, I think jQuery.html() would also work the same way, but the code would be cleaner: http://api.jquery.com/html/